# Huge inefficiency using in conditional as opposed to simple or conditionals

Tags: sql, oracle

My query is as structured as follows:

```
select
  distinct items,
  invoice
from
  table_name
where
  location = 'warehouse'
  and invoice in 
   (select 
      t.invoice
    from
      list_name t
    where
      t.invoice_date > to_date (('2015-04-18'),'yyyy-mm-dd')
   )
```

The subquery should give me a list of invoices which i then return into the main query to find all the items in the invoice. The number of invoices is not static which is why i wanted to nest a subquery.

The problem with this query is it might take hours to process as opposed to:

```
select
  distinct items,
  invoice
from
  table_name
where
  location = 'warehouse'
  and t.invoice = 'invoice1'
  or  t.invoice = 'invoice2'
```

which takes about .3 seconds. I tried limiting my in condition to two values here:

```
select
  distinct items,
  invoice
from
  table_name
where
  location = 'warehouse'
  and invoice in ('invoice1','invoice2')
```

This query still takes about 4 minutes to run. Any ideas why this takes so long? I've used the in condition before where it was never this extremely slow, but I can't figure out why this particular implementation isn't working.

edit* Here's the explain plan. Which is the same for the second and third block of code after fixing the problem @hines pointed out.

```
Description                               object                  cost

select statement, goal=all_rows                                   422542
  hash unique                                                     422542
    view                                 index$_join$_001         422541
      hash join
        index range scan                 PKHIR_IX19               31382
        index fast full scan             PKHIR_IX16               351172
```

Comment: You should join the two tables based on invoice value and add the filter `t.invoice in ('invoice1','invoice2')` on the where clause. Make sure that that column `invoice` has an index on both table.

Comment: Have you looked at the execution plans for all three queries, looked at index definitions, and checked your stats are up-to-date?

Comment: Show us your table and index definitions.  Perhaps you have something set up incorrectly.

Comment: As @AlexPoole just have said, attach plans at first. Also, it will be better if you will show table structure

Comment: @agent5566 i edited the plans into the main posts. What do you mean by showing the table structure?

Comment: @JonathanPinlac, I mean tables DDL, and plans should be for all three queries ;)

Comment: DDL = the CREATE TABLE and CREATE INDEX statements used to create the tables and indexes.

Answer (score 1):

The criteria you are using is different between the second and third code block. If you are trying to replicate the IN codition then you would want to bracket around the 'or' statement. Currently the 'or' statement would return any row with t.invoice = 'invoice2' even if location didn't equal 'warehouse'.

```
select
  distinct items,
  invoice
from
  table_name
where
  location = 'warehouse'
  and (invoice = 'invoice1'
       or invoice = 'invoice2')
```

Comment: Note, there's no `t` table alias.

Comment: Ah, updating that second block of code makes it as slow as the in conditional one.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar case someday and rebuilding query to something like this made wonders:

```
select distinct items, invoice
  from table_name a
  where location = 'warehouse'
     and exists (
       select 1
         from list_name t
         where t.invoice_date > to_date (('2015-04-18'),'yyyy-mm-dd') 
           and t.invoice = a.invoice )
```